# How to feed a raster map with values from other raster map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, tools

I would like to know if there is a tool able to "feed" a current raster map with the values from other raster map (so the values from the current raster map will be replaced by the ones from the other raster map) in order to get exactly the same extent for both raster maps.
I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: Can you be more specific?Have your files the same pixel size? what kind of values do you mean?? Perhaps raster calculator is your answer.

Comment: Yes, both of them have pixels of 250m and are in the same spatial reference system. Both raster maps are categorical, and the values are integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using Spatial Analyst Tools > Generalization > [Nibble](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000038000000)

> Replaces cells of a raster corresponding to a mask with the values of
>   the nearest neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

As geo_dd pointed out, the raster calculator tool (Spatial Analyst Tools > Map Algebra > Raster Calculation) should do the trick [here you can find some examples of calculations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000zn000000)

Comment: Okay, I'll figure out how to do it with Raster Calculator. Thank you.

Comment: I would look into the Con function, it is similar to a if statement in Excel. Would you like to share your data so we can see possible solutions?

Comment: I finally did it. I only had to use the Nibble tool from the Spatial Analyst. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Aweasome! I didn't know about the Nibble tool, I will look into it!